# Cisco router on a stick with public ip wan (ISP)gateway

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, nat, trunk

I am trying to create a router on a stick with an outside facing sub-interface with a public IP from an ISP. I have tried to configure NAT and routing but I just cant get to ping the internet. I'm using a cisco 2811 router and a 2960 switch.

This is the topology I would like to achieve

[image]

Currently this are my running configurations

2811 Router

```
Current configuration : 2430 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname r1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $xxxxxx
!
no aaa new-model
dot11 syslog
!
!
ip cef
!
!
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
voice-card 0
 no dspfarm
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
username xxxx privilege 15 secret 5 $xxxxxxxxx
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 ip address 10.1.1.254 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 10.1.10.254 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 10.1.20.254 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.155
 encapsulation dot1Q 155
 ip address 197.221.155.30 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
router eigrp 100
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 197.221.155.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip default-gateway 197.221.155.29
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 197.221.155.29
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/0.155 overload
!
access-list 1 permit any
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
banner login ^C^C
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
!
end
```

and for the 2960 switch

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 4603 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname sw1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $xxxxx..
!
username xxx privilege 15 secret 5 $xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
!
!
no aaa new-model
system mtu routing 1500
!
!
!
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-3654552704
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-3654552704
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-3654552704
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-3654552704
 certificate self-signed 01

  quit
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface FastEthernet0/25
!
interface FastEthernet0/26
!
interface FastEthernet0/27
!
interface FastEthernet0/28
!
interface FastEthernet0/29
!
interface FastEthernet0/30
!
interface FastEthernet0/31
!
interface FastEthernet0/32
!
interface FastEthernet0/33
!
interface FastEthernet0/34
!
interface FastEthernet0/35
!
interface FastEthernet0/36
!
interface FastEthernet0/37
!
interface FastEthernet0/38
!
interface FastEthernet0/39
!
interface FastEthernet0/40
!
interface FastEthernet0/41
!
interface FastEthernet0/42
!
interface FastEthernet0/43
!
interface FastEthernet0/44
!
interface FastEthernet0/45
!
interface FastEthernet0/46
!
interface FastEthernet0/47
!
interface FastEthernet0/48
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 155
 switchport mode access
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 10.1.1.253 255.255.255.0
!
ip default-gateway 10.1.1.254
ip http server
ip http secure-server
banner login ^C^C
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
end
```

show vlan on 2960 switch

```
VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    Fa0/1, Fa0/2, Fa0/3, Fa0/4
                                                Fa0/5, Fa0/6, Fa0/7, Fa0/8
                                                Fa0/9, Fa0/11, Fa0/12, Fa0/13
                                                Fa0/14, Fa0/15, Fa0/16, Fa0/17
                                                Fa0/18, Fa0/19, Fa0/20, Fa0/21
                                                Fa0/22, Fa0/23, Fa0/24, Fa0/25
                                                Fa0/26, Fa0/27, Fa0/28, Fa0/29
                                                Fa0/30, Fa0/31, Fa0/32, Fa0/33
                                                Fa0/34, Fa0/35, Fa0/36, Fa0/37
                                                Fa0/38, Fa0/39, Fa0/40, Fa0/41
                                                Fa0/42, Fa0/43, Fa0/44, Fa0/45
                                                Fa0/46, Fa0/47, Fa0/48, Gi0/1
                                                Gi0/2, Gi0/3
10   VLAN0010                         active
20   VLAN0020                         active
155  ISP-Airtel                       active    Gi0/4
1002 fddi-default                     act/unsup
1003 token-ring-default               act/unsup
1004 fddinet-default                  act/unsup
1005 trnet-default                    act/unsup

VLAN Type  SAID       MTU   Parent RingNo BridgeNo Stp  BrdgMode Trans1 Trans2
---- ----- ---------- ----- ------ ------ -------- ---- -------- ------ ------
1    enet  100001     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0
10   enet  100010     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0
20   enet  100020     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0
155  enet  100155     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0
1002 fddi  101002     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0
1003 tr    101003     1500  -      -      -        -    -        0      0
1004 fdnet 101004     1500  -      -      -        ieee -        0      0
1005 trnet 101005     1500  -      -      -        ibm  -        0      0

Remote SPAN VLANs
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Primary Secondary Type              Ports
------- --------- ----------------- ------------------------------------------
```

traceroute 8.8.8.8 on my 2811 router gives this output

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8

Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to dns.google (8.8.8.8)

  1 197.221.155.161 12 msec 16 msec 16 msec
  2 teng-0-0-0-3-PE2-kpl.liquidtelecom.net (41.222.1.86) 12 msec 12 msec 16 msec
  3 ipt-41-222-1-85.liquidtelecom.net (41.222.1.85) 20 msec 16 msec 12 msec
  4 te-0-0-1-0.lug-p2-kpl.liquidtelecom.net (197.155.94.150) [MPLS: Label 24073 Exp 0] 28 msec
    41.222.0.181 [MPLS: Label 24029 Exp 0] 28 msec
    41.222.0.159 [MPLS: Label 24073 Exp 0] 28 msec
  5 te-0-5-0-6.lke-p1-nbi.liquidtelecom.net (197.155.94.220) [MPLS: Label 24062 Exp 0] 28 msec
    te-0-5-0-7.lke-p1-nbi.liquidtelecom.net (197.155.94.222) [MPLS: Label 24062 Exp 0] 28 msec
    te-0-5-0-5.lke-p1-nbi.liquidtelecom.net (197.155.94.126) [MPLS: Label 24062 Exp 0] 28 msec
  6 et-0-1-10.lke-p1-mbs.liquidtelecom.net (197.155.94.217) [MPLS: Label 928698 Exp 0] 36 msec 32 msec
    et-1-1-8.lke-p2-msa.liquidtelecom.net (197.155.94.9) [MPLS: Label 859512 Exp 0] 36 msec
  7 hu-0-3-0-0.lke-pe1-msa.liquidtelecom.net (197.155.94.168) 28 msec 28 msec 32 msec
  8 196.216.70.222 28 msec 28 msec 32 msec
  9 172.253.53.65 28 msec
    172.253.53.49 28 msec
    172.253.53.65 32 msec
 10 209.85.249.141 32 msec 32 msec 28 msec
 11 dns.google (8.8.8.8) 32 msec 28 msec 32 msec
```

traceroute 8.8.8.8  on my 2960 route gives

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8

Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 8.8.8.8

  1 10.1.1.254 0 msec 0 msec 0 msec
  2  *  *  *
  3  *  *  *
  4  *  *  *
  5  *  *  *
  6  *  *  * 
  7  *  *  * 
  8  *  *  * 
  9  *  *  * 
 10  *  *  * 
 11  *  *  * 
 12  *  *  * 
 13  *  *  * 
 14  *  *  * 
 15  *  *  * 
 16  *  *  * 
 17  *  *  * 
 18  *  *  * 
 19  *  *  * 
 20  *  *  * 
 21  *  *  * 
 22  *  *  * 
 23  *  *  *
```

I need some assistance to successfully configure a router on a stick with a public IP WAN gateway. I am new to Cisco

Comment: Where are you getting the DHCP information for the local hosts? Also, you do not set a default gateway on a router that is routing; you use the default route that you have configured. Why are you running EIGRP? you have no other router to peer it with. Routing protocols do not route, so you are just wasting router CPU cycles

Comment: Kha, can you provide the output of the VLAN database on the switch? Can use `show vlan` or `show vlan-switch` depending on IOS.

Comment: @ditrapanij I have added the show vlan output in the question. Thank you.

Comment: I still would like to know where the PCs are being assigned addresses. You have not configured a DHCP server on the router, and there is not a stand-alone DHCP server on the drawing, and it would require helper addresses configured on the router, and you do not have that.

Comment: Along with what Ron has asked for, the output of some troubleshooting would be awesome too. E.g. traceroute/ping from a host, traceroute/ping from the router, ARP & Routing table on the router, MAC address table on the switch. Maybe even the NAT translations -> `show ip nat translations` from the Router too.

Comment: Thank @RonMaupin, The DHCP server I can configure that, I'm comfortable with that. What I need now is to get isp connection working and be able to ping outside world from router and switch. After that I'll do ahead and add client devices with static IPs or configure a DHCP server.

Comment: @ditrapanij I have added traceroute output for both router and switch to the question. show ip nat translations gives no output on the router. From the traceroute output I think packets from my switch are not beigh routed properly. I can ping google from the router but not switch.

Comment: I just copied your exact configuration into a Lab and cannot replicate your fault. The fact you're not seeing anything in the NAT translations points towards a NAT issue on the Router as the traffic is reaching 10.1.1.254, however I cannot see anything visibly wrong. Out of curiosity, do you see access-list 1 incrementing if you do `show ip access-lists`?

Comment: Thanks @ditrapanij `show ip access-lists` Gives no output on the router. I don't see incrementation.

Comment: Hi @RonMaupin, Do I need to disable eigrp? I'm only using one router and one switch. From the router I can ping google.com but I am not able to do it from the switch or a pc when I configure it with an Ip

Comment: EIGRP does nothing for you. You only run a routing protocol when you need to share routing information among multiple routers. EIGRP is sending out packets, looking for other EIGRP routers, so you should really remove it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to optimize your nat translation by nat timeout

```
ip nat translation timeout 300
ip nat translation tcp-timeout 180
ip nat translation udp-timeout 120
ip nat translation finrst-timeout 30
ip nat translation syn-timeout 30
ip nat translation dns-timeout 30
ip nat translation icmp-timeout 120
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create sub interface with public ip . You need to assign public ip for outside interface of router . Ànd do natting nat overload

`Router(config) # access-list 1 permit ip 10.0.0.0 any`

`IP NAT inside source list 1 interface "router outside interface" overload`

`IP route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 point towards gateway of ISP`